# What does 줬는데요 mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, verb-endings, suffix

**What does `줬는데요` mean?**

**What's the root word for  `줬는데요`?**

For example in this sentence from the [vlive video](http://endic.naver.com/vliveExample.nhn?sLn=en&videoId=12780&subtitleNo=3541880&query=%EC%9C%A0%EB%8B%88%EC%BD%98+%EC%9D%B8%ED%98%95%EB%8F%84+%EC%9E%88%EC%96%B4%EC%9A%94.+%EC%A0%9C%EA%B0%80+%EC%9D%B4%EB%A6%84%EB%8F%84+%EB%B6%99%EC%97%AC%EC%A4%AC%EB%8A%94%EB%8D%B0%EC%9A%94.)

```
유니콘 인형도 있어요. 제가 이름도 붙여줬는데요.
I have a unicorn doll. I gave a name to it.
```

`이름도 붙여줬는데요` here means "naming" / "name giving"

Another example from [Strong Woman](https://www.viki.com/videos/1116527v-strong-woman-do-bong-soon-episode-10):

```
지난 밤 4번째 납치 사건이 발생하면서 또 한번 충격을 줬는데요
Last night a fourth kidnapping incident occurred which has caused us great shock once again.
```

Here `충격을 줬는데요` means "gave a shock"

And when I search on Naver dictionary, it shows which has the root word as `주다` "to give" http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=en&searchOption=all&query=%EC%A4%AC%EB%8A%94%EB%8D%B0%EC%9A%94

Most probably, `줬` comes from `주` but **what does the rest of the suffixes mean in `줬는데요`?**

**Why did the `ㅜ` become <s>`ㅟ`</s> `ㅝ` and added the pachim `ㅆ`?** Is that a common "mutation"?

Comment: 주 (주다) + 었 (past tense) + 는데요 -> 주었는데요 -> 줬는데요

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful, the `ㅜ` (`주다`) conjugated to `ᅯ`(`줘`) (not as `ᅱ` as said in the question).

`줬는데요` has several things going on, lets break it down:

1. The verb is `주다` (meaning: to give). `주다` has been conjugated into the **past tense**, giving: `줬다`. That is why `ㅆ` is added.
2. `는데요` is a versatile helper verb form with a few different meanings. In the Lee Hi's vlive case, it seems the use case is: providing some background (on her doll) [TTMIK lesson on ~는데](https://secure-hwcdn.libsyn.com/p/1/0/3/1034b898caec055d/ttmik-l3l21.pdf?c_id=2559501&expiration=1518929465&hwt=8018f4261c49922bba3de7d2dd277646)